# Typescript generics for a polymorphic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, narrowing

I would like to correctly type the following function:

```js
const noCI = itOrDescribe => (isCI ? itOrDescribe.skip : itOrDescribe)
```

Here's my first attempt:

```
const noCI = <T extends Mocha.SuiteFunction | Mocha.TestFunction>(itOrDescribe: T) => (isCI ? itOrDescribe.skip : itOrDescribe)
```

By 'correctly', I mean that the code should correctly infer that if `describe` which is of type `Mocha.SuiteFunction` gets passed in, the return type should be `Mocha.SuiteFunction | Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction`, and if `it` gets passed in, the return type should be `Mocha.TestFunction | Mocha.PendingTestFunction`.

Instead, the type is always inferred as `Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction | Mocha.PendingTestFunction`, regardless of which type gets passed in. Why?

To put my generics question more generically, I want a function that takes either a type A or a type B, and depending on whether A or B is passed, return a type derived from either A or B.

Comment: Could you [edit] to make the code a [mre] that doesn't depend on third-party types or values?

Comment: @jcalz sure, I'll work on it.

Comment: Skipping tests on CI is _probably_ a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't like the type Typescript infers, you can always just annotate it yourself.

And in this case that looks like: `T | T['skip']`.

```
import Mocha, { it, describe } from 'mocha'

declare const isCI: boolean

const noCI = <
  T extends Mocha.SuiteFunction | Mocha.TestFunction
>(itOrDescribe: T): T | T['skip'] => (
  isCI ? itOrDescribe.skip : itOrDescribe
)

const noCiIt = noCI(it)
// Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction | Mocha.PendingTestFunction

const noCiDescribe = noCI(describe)
// Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction | Mocha.PendingTestFunction

noCiDescribe('test', () => {
  noCiIt('test', () => {
    //...
  })
})
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAWQgYwBYEMA0cDedgzYAmApgM7JTABGJcAvnAGZQQhwDkIKGHAUH1LIANuih1kEAHZl4wMgGEAkgC441CBGEl0UgZJnwpEZXAC8cADx84cACpwSADxgkpRMoh7oAdAGUAVwISADEAqWQYYGk4AB8vNF87chgwiKjpPgA+AAoCAHkoABFyShoSNTsASkq4+wBtDjIAa2AwDgBdcyy4HJt8RSU4AH58GEKSiipaHxa2uDUC4tLpkj4q-WlZOGMFYCV4C12lPJgNgHpz21sAPWHNwx2TYEmy2nMn5RzSKfKLq+udwEuxeK3KOQ4rlkHGwOSq3Vw-RBBwhUJgMN68LMPRw-Vslx8hP69A2JKAA)

Comment: I came up with a similar annotation on my own, but yours is cleaner and makes better use of inference: `type NoCIFn = <T extends (Mocha.SuiteFunction | Mocha.TestFunction)>(itOrDescribe: T) => T extends Mocha.SuiteFunction ? (Mocha.SuiteFunction | Mocha.PendingSuiteFunction) : (Mocha.TestFunction | Mocha.PendingTestFunction)`